# How to redirect subsite to another subsite

Tags: .htaccess, web, server, webserver, cpanel

I have a site `example.com`.

And I am trying to redirect the `www.example.com/series` to `www.example.com/product` using `.htaccess`.

and any action after series to append to product for example `www.example.com/series/{123}` to `www.example.com/product/{123}`

How can I do this using `.htaccess`?

Comment: Please do share your htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RewriteRule and have something like that :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} !http://example.com$">
    RewriteRule ^series$   /product [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^series/([0-9]+)/$   /product/$1/ [R=301,L]
</If>
```

But it depend of the rewrite you may already have on your htaccess.

Comment: I have multiple site under the same shared hosting, using this also makes other website with series to go to product.
I just want the specific website example.com/series to go to example.com/product

Comment: You can use a RewriteCond, i have updated my anwser. The condition test the domain and apply rewrite only if it match. <if> need apache 2.4, if you have an old version you can use inline version : RewriteCond  ```%{HTTP_HOST}  !^https://exemple.com$```